# Differentiation method for evaluating $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{3^n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, summation

I evaluated the following infinite sum (the original and broader question regarding this sum can be found at [Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{3^n} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261114/evaluating-sum-n-1-infty-fracn23n)).

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{3^n} $$

However, I'm getting the feeling that I made some mistake(s) during my evaluations. My particular concern regards the changes made in the sum's index. The following is what I did.

I first defined a power series as the function f.

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{3^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 (\frac{1}{3})^n = f(\frac{1}{3}) \Rightarrow f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 x^n $$

I then attempted to manipulate the sum in order to transform it through the geometric series. This is where I'm quite unsure whether I did everything correctly. One of the things I did here looks wrong to me, but somehow, I still ended up with the correct answer (which is 3/2).

$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 x^n
\\ &= x \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 x^{n-1}
\\ &= x \frac{d}{dx} ( \sum_{n=0}^\infty n x^n )
\\ &= x \frac{d}{dx} ( x \sum_{n=0}^\infty n x^{n-1} )
\\ &= x \frac{d}{dx} ( x \frac{d}{dx} ( \sum_{n=-1}^\infty x^n ) )
\\ &= x \frac{d}{dx} ( x \frac{d}{dx} ( \frac{1}{1-x} ) )
\\ &= x \frac{d}{dx} ( x \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} )
\\ &= x \frac{d}{dx} ( \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} )
\\ &= x \frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}
\\ &= \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}
\\ &\Rightarrow f(\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{3}{2}
\end{align*}
$$

The main concern of mine is the transition step to the closed-form geometric series. Of course, the proper equation for a geometric series is this:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x} $$

However, what I did is this:

$$ \sum_{n=-1}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x} $$

The difference here is that the starting index is -1 instead of 0. This makes my translation of the sum incorrect. And yet, I still get the correct answer. On the other hand, I've tried the correct(?) form of an infinite geometric series that starts at n=-1:

$$ \sum_{n=-1}^\infty x^n = \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1-x} = \frac{1}{x(1-x)} $$

However, this yields an incorrect answer.

I'm guessing that the final index I should've had for the sum was n=0 instead of n=-1. I'm guessing I did something wrong with the index shifts caused by the derivatives? Either way, I'm not seeing it.

I do realize that there are other ways to go about evaluating this sum, but I'd really like to understand this derivative method.

Comment: What makes you think the (anti-)derivatives change the starting points of the sums

Comment: I guess that they technically don't, but I'm used to increasing the sum index by one when differentiating a power series since a constant becomes 0. I figured that taking the antiderivative here would be the reverse and actually introduce new constants to the sum, but I guess that isn't the case, haha.

Comment: When you say $n^2x^{n-1}= \frac{d}{dy}\left(n x^n\right)$, you do not change the value of $n$, just the power, as in $2^2x^1=\frac{d}{dy}\left(2 x^2\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a step $$\displaystyle x \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 x^{n-1} = x \frac{d}{dx} ( \sum_{n=0}^\infty n x^n )$$ which introduces an unnecessary $n=0$ term and $$\displaystyle x \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 x^{n-1} = x \frac{d}{dx} ( \sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^n )$$ would be better. It does not make your answer wrong, since $nx^n=0$ when $n=0$, but there is no justification for it.

You then do the same unnecessary thing again to start a later sum at $n=-1$ when that sum could start at $n=1$.

So you should have had $$f(x) = x \frac{d}{dx} \left( x \frac{d}{dx} \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \right) \right)= x \frac{d}{dx} \left( x \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{x}{1-x} \right) \right) = \frac{x\,\left( x+1\right) }{{\left( 1-x\right) }^{3}}$$ which is what you ended up with anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that you have
$$
\sum_{n=\color{red}{0}}^\infty r^n=\frac {\color{red}{1}}{1-r}, \quad |r|<1,
$$ **but**
$$
\sum_{n=\color{red}{1}}^\infty r^n=\frac {\color{red}{r}}{1-r}, \quad |r|<1.
$$ since
$$
\sum_{n=\color{red}{1}}^\infty r^n=r\sum_{n=\color{red}{1}}^\infty r^{n-1}=r\sum_{n=\color{red}{0}}^\infty r^{n}.
$$
May be this can help.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a step in which you write

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) & = \cdots \\
     & = x \frac{d}{dx} \left( x \sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1} \right) \\
     & = \color{red}{
         x \frac{d}{dx} \left( x \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} \right)} \\
     & = x \frac{d}{dx} \left( x \frac{d}{dx}
                        \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \right) \right) \\
     & = \cdots
\end{align}
$$

since $nx^{n-1} = 0$ when $n = 0$.  That should resolve matters, although it isn't in fact necessary, because$\ldots$

ETA: Actually, your line is in error.  You write

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) & = \cdots \\
     & = x \frac{d}{dx} \left( x \sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1} \right) \\
     & = x \frac{d}{dx} \left( x \frac{d}{dx}
                        \left( \sum_{n=-1}^\infty x^n \right) \right) \\
     & = \cdots
\end{align}
$$

but the index limit should have remained $n = 0$, since

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) & = \cdots \\
     & = x \frac{d}{dx} \left( x \sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1} \right) \\
     & = \color{red}{
         x \frac{d}{dx} \left( x \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dx} x^n \right)} \\
     & = x \frac{d}{dx} \left( x \frac{d}{dx}
                        \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \right) \right) \\
     & = \cdots
\end{align}
$$